# How to using @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * *") automatically Generate xls report in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am trying to  automatically Generate xls report using @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * *") on particular time but Its not working .Please anyone give Idea.Thank you

Comment: your problem is that the cron is not executed? some exception?

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * *")
 public void freezeDateTwo(){
  System.out.println("shudler Working");
  service.updateFreezeOnDateTwoAndSixteen();
  List<ExtusrRole> user = service.getExtUser();
  excelReport(user);
 }     private ModelAndView excelReport(List<ExtusrRole> user) {
  System.out.println("excelReport");
  return new ModelAndView("excelView", "tourPlan", user);
 }    This corn run successfully each 1min but the last return only its not working... sir Pls Its there any solution... Its no produce the error..

Comment: I mean, when you run your app or debug it, did you see some exception in your logs? the app goes to the method freezeDataTwo()?

Comment: Yes freezeDataTwo() method is working good and print "excelReport" is successfully...but Its not return.. and no shows  exception in this place..pls help me..

Comment: What you are trying is wrong, you want to refresh your view every minute with the data of some users, or you want to download an excel file with users data. Better if you add to your question what is your functional goal

Comment: My functional goal is ... Its automatically generate the excel sheet every day In spring MVC .... Please give me idea or any refer link in this task ... and thank you for yours....:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135573/discussion-between-cralfaro-and-balamurugan-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi according to with what you are trying to do, I would use this approach:

1. Use the cron to generate a report file every day and store it in some specific location
2. Create a URL to read any report by dd/MM/yyyy

So technically would be something like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * *") 
public void freezeDateTwo(){ 
    System.out.println("shudler Working");
    service.updateFreezeOnDateTwoAndSixteen(); 
    List<ExtusrRole> user = service.getExtUser(); 
    excelReport(user); 
    //In this point you should have created a report in some specific location
}
```

In your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reports/{dd}/{mm}/{yyyy}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
private void excelReport(@PathVariable("dd") Integer day,
                         @PathVariable("mm") Integer month,
                         @PathVariable("yyyy") Integer year,
                         HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("excelReport"); 
    //Search from your specific location the right report
    File file = //Your file  
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName()));
    response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
}
```